# Conda environments includes packages from different environment

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

Hi everyone I have a strange problem with packages installed via pip in conda environments. I want to set up two conda environments: **env1** and **env2** using yml files as e.g. the following (only the packages installed via pip vary in **env2**)

```
name: env1

channels:
  - defaults
  - anaconda-fusion

dependencies:
  - cudatoolkit=9.0=1
  - cudnn=7.6.0=cuda9.0_0
  - pip=19.1.1
  - python=3.6.5
  - shapely==1.6.4
  - pip:
    - argparse==1.4.0
    - BeautifulSoup4==4.7.1
    - cython==0.28.5
    - h5py==2.9.0
    - imageio==2.5.0
    - imgaug==0.2.9
    - imutils==0.5.2
    ...
```

If I install **env1** everything works fine. Activating **env1** and typing *pip list -v* shows that all packages are located in *C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env1\Lib\site-packages* as it should be. Now I deactivate **env1** and install **env2** and that is where the problem occurs. It is desired that all packages listed in the yml of **env2** are installed separately for **env2** and located in *C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env2\Lib\site-packages*. Instead all packages that are also in **env1** are considered to be already installed and only the reminder is installed in **env2**. Activating **env2** and typing *pip list -v* shows all packages I need but most of them are located in *C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env1\Lib\site-packages* and only the 'new' ones in *C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env2\Lib\site-packages*. It seems like **env2** has some kind of visibilty or access to **env1**. This is higly unwanted and causes particular severe problems if **env1** and **env2** have same packages with different versions. Reinstallation of Anaconda did not work. I could not find any suspicious entry in environment varaibles either. Anyone some helpful thoughts or ideas? Would be appreciated a lot.

Edit: Would like to add that the entire procedure works fine on several other systems. What could cause the error on one specific system?

Comment: It would be useful, you also tell how exactly you are creating the env2 environment.
To me it seems like env1 became kind of default python at least from the point of view of env2.

Comment: I simply use 'conda env create -f env1.yml' and 'conda env create -f env2.yml', with the yml files looking like in the post. Before installing env1 or env2 I made sure to open a new prompt so no other environment is activated. Do you know how to check whether one environment becomes 'default'?

Comment: Have you tried installing it via the anaconda navigator?